# Limit drop down based on a flag on a model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I would like to limit the options of a drop down box based on a status column on a table in rails.  For example this model would have a status flag of T or F.  If the row was T I would like it to display as an option in the drop down box.  Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't be hard, just make a class method in the model that returns a hash, pass in whatever info you need (the T or F) and as long as it returns a hash form helper should be able to parse it.  I fill select boxes all the time using Model contants, same principle.